# How to access method parameters while inside of a Runnable defined on the fly

Tags: java, android, parameters, runnable

Here is my code:

```
public void showScore(Player winner)
{
    view.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            String scored = view.getString(R.string.scored_a_goal);
            String score = view.getString(R.string.score);

            Toast.makeText(view,winner.name+" "+view.getString(R.string.scored_a_goal),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Now everything is fine except for I cannot access winner(of type Player) from inside the Runnable, what is the work around for this?

Comment: If you declare the parameter final then you can just use it how you would in the originating method (like normal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define `winner` as `final Player winner` and this code should work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is your IDE you are using, most modern Java IDEs will help you with that, just make the winner `final` and everything will go fine.